# Django + Visual Studio в боевом режиме

Tags: python, visual-studio

Доброе утро. 
Есть желание создать проект Django с помощью MS Visual Studio 2015 с расширением PTVS. На хостинге Джино у меня есть самый обычный домен, на котором я и хочу вести разработку. Хостер рекомендует использовать virtualenv (Питон 2.7). Проект на соседнем домене крутится тоже в виртуальном окружении. Как бы мне создать VS-проект(решение) прямо на этом домене и виртуальной среде?

SSH/FTP, разумеется есть. Смутно припоминаю, что в PyCharm можно было указать удаленный интерпретатор.

Comment: Зачем вести разработку прямо на сервере?

Comment: На встроенном тестовом сервере джанги при локальной разработке, все работает как по маслу, зато при переносе на боевой сервер все перестает работать. В прошлый раз мне так и не удалось его заставить увидеть статические файлы (надо было переделывать буквально всё), поэтому хочу все подобные проблемы выявлять сразу же. Получается - затратил время на разработку, а потом на развертывание еще столько же. И в конце-концов, это лишь учёба :)

Comment: Вот в рамках учёбы лучше сразу учиться делать сайты независимыми от окружения ;) Да и правильному способу разработки учиться тоже не помешает: сперва собственно разработка на локальной машине, потом тестирование на каком-нибудь CI, потом выкатывание на staging-сервер и уже только потом выкатывание на хостинг с доменом